# Facebook auth dialog says "Okay, go to application" instead of "Allow"

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

What happend?

Now the permissions dialog doesn't say allow anymore, but "Okay, go to application" (which doesn't do anything)...

What happend? What can I do?? My applications doesn't work any more... :-(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the "Enhanced Auth Dialog" which Facebook set to "Enabled" per default. But it doesn't work!